# php How can I replace a character in a string (only) when it is in a certain place?

Tags: php, string, replace

the result when I var_dump is:

```
string(3) "100" string(3) "001" string(3) "011"
```

Now with str_replace i can replace a 1 with the word COW for example

which results in

cow00 00cow and 0cowcow

But what I need is:

when the 1 is in position 1 it needs to be cow
when the 1 is in position 2 it needs to be pig
when the 1 is in position 3 it needs to be horse

which would result in the version i'm looking for:

cow 0 0
0 0 horse
0 pig horse

What is the easiest way to solve this little puzzel? :)

Comment: I'm new to regex but isn't that kind of case exactly made for regexes?

Comment: Otherwise, string to array, check elements one by one, will work 100% and will be easy to implement, but might not be the most efficientway

Comment: Is it PHP you are talking about?

Comment: damn i'm completely off topic, I'm answering in obj-C.
Today is not my day...

Comment: In PHP you can also loop over a string as char array `for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){ echo $string[$i]."\n"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks take, that works, but... 
it only works for 1. and i need it for all...

[edited]

this is my solution (incl. a much better example, gas break throttle)

```
foreach($result as $part){

    $string = $part;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){ 

    if ($i == 0 && $string[$i] == 1) {
        echo " break ";
        continue;
    }
    if ($i == 1 && $string[$i] == 1) {
        echo " gas ";
        continue;
    }
    if ($i == 2 && $string[$i] == 1) {
        echo " throttle ";
        continue;
    }

    if ($i == 0 && $string[$i] == 0) {
        echo "  ";
        continue;
    }
    if ($i == 1 && $string[$i] == 0) {
        echo "  ";
        continue;
    }
    if ($i == 2 && $string[$i] == 0) {
        echo "  ";
        continue;
    }


    echo $string[$i]."<br>"."\t";
}  

    echo $part."<br/>"."\t";     

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT : THIS ANSWER IS OFF TOPIC BECAUSE OF OBJECTIVE-C LANGUAGE.**

Sorry, I don't know how I got there thinking it was obj-c. Anyway, logic could be the same but sorry for this.

This method should work but I don't know if it's optimal. I typed it here so there might be some mistakes here and there

```
- (NSString *)transformStringIntoPigsAndStuff:(NSString*)baseString{
     if (baseString.length >3){
        return nil;
    }

    NSArray *arrSplitString = [baseString componentsSeparatedByString:@""];

    int count = 0;
    NSMutableString *finalString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    for (NSString *str in arrSplitString){

        switch (count) {
            case 0:
                if (str.intValue == 1){
                    [finalString appendString:@"cow"];
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (str.intValue == 1){
                    [finalString appendString:@"pig"];
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (str.intValue == 1){
                    [finalString appendString:@"horse"];
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        count++;
    }

    return finalString;
}
```

Like i said in a comment, isn't a regex the best way to solve this?

Also note, this is not dynamic at all and only works with your triplets strings. It would require a little more work to adapt to any string lenght.

Answer (score 1):

@Zils Answer in PHP:

```
<?php
    $string = "101";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){ 
        if ($i == 0 && $string[$i] == "1") {
            echo "cow";
            continue;
        }
        if ($i == 1 && $string[$i] == "1") {
            echo "pig";
            continue;
        }
        if ($i == 2 && $string[$i] == "1") {
            echo "horse";
            continue;
        }
        echo $string[$i];
    }
```